# NodeJS How to use a property to set another property in module.exports?

Tags: node.js

```
module.exports.views = {
  theme: 'themes/theme1/',
  layout: this.theme + 'layout'
};
```

I want the layout property to depend on the theme property. However, when run, the layout property seems to be undefined. What did I do wrong? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to refer to the object being created via object literal notation from within the notation itself. At the moment, `this` refers to the window, or global in node.js's case.

You will need to return the value with a getter function.

```
module.exports.views = {
    theme: 'themes/theme1/',
    layout: function() {
        return this.theme + 'layout';
    }
};
```

Or you can turn it into a constructor.

```
module.exports.views = function() {
    this.theme = 'themes/theme1/';
    this.layout = this.theme + 'layout';
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. it worked perfectly.. I'm curious though about the performance.. Which is more efficient? this answer or the answer below by @pomeh... just wondering..

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code `this.theme + 'layout'`, `this` does not refers to your `views` object but it refers to the global object, which as no `theme` property.

This should work:

```
var view = {};
view.theme = 'themes/theme1/';
view.layout = view.theme + 'layout';

module.exports.views = view;
```